# What is the major benefit of Active-Active in AWS routing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I came across the so called `Active-Active` or `Active-Passive` routing. Diagrammed as below.

For the later `Active-Passive`:

[image]

It is easy to understand: Passive (HTTP Server 2) is the Standby service/instance for Active (HTTP Server 1) to fail over.

For the first one Active-Active:

[image]

I don't understand what is the major benefit though, it seems to me both service/instance must be up and running the same level and the routing is maybe just something like `round robin`, wouldn't this be kind of resource/cost wasting? Does it introduce extra computing power? what is the use case for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In active-passive mode one web server is sitting there costing you money but not serving any requests. If a sudden surge in traffic came in the extra web server would not be able to help absorb the extra load. The only time the second web server starts being used is when the first web server crashes and can no longer serve requests. This gives you failover in the event of a server crash, but does not help you at all in the event of a sudden surge in traffic.

In active-active mode each web server is serving some of the traffic. In order to scale out your web servers (horizontal scaling) you would have two or more servers, all in "active" mode serving some portion of the web requests. If a sudden surge in traffic comes in, that surge is spread across multiple servers which can hopefully absorb the load, and new servers can be added automatically by AWS as needed, and removed when no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks. So the Active-Active model seems to be pretty much like already auto-scaled? Why not use only one Active server and scale out only when needed?

Comment: @mdivk the active-active model is the model you would have to follow if you wanted to use auto-scaling. The active-passive model is not auto-scaling compatible, it is only for failover/disaster recovery.